# Find all mongo documents containing a field with a specific value using java

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am trying to use mongo's Java driver to read through a collection and only pull back documents with a field that is a range of values. An example of this would be if I had data like

```
{ "name" : "foo", "Color" : "white", "Date" : 20171116 }
{ "name" : "bar", "Color" : "black", "Date" : 20171115 }
{ "name" : "Jeff", "Color" : "purple", "Date" : 20171114 }
{ "name" : "John", "Color" : "blue", "Date" : 20171015 }
```

I would want to begin on 20171114 and end on 20171116 so I would do something like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String begin = "20171114";
String end   = "20171116";
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
```

Then I would need to convert the strings to a date and use a cursor like

```
try {
  startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
  endDate = df.parse(endDateString);
  BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
  data.put("Date", new BasicDBObject( new BasicDBOject( "$gte", startDate).append("$lte", endDate)));
} catch(ParseException e){
  e.printStackTrace
}
```

However when I do this it returns nothing.

**Answer:**

I was trying to compare a number to a date which doesn't work so I converted my begin & end string to integers by doing

```
Integer beginDate = Integer.valueOf(begin)
Integer endDate = Integer.valueOf(end)
```

and it worked.

Comment: Your `Date` field is "numeric" and not a `Date` object.

Comment: Then I could change the begin/end strings to ints instead of dates however I would run into the problem of how to handle grabbing dates from 20171030 to 20171102 right?

Comment: How? Think about it. You can store the data however you want, but a "date" is not a "number" like an "orange" is not an "apple", and that is the essence of your question and why you get no result. You want a result, then query with the same type as what the data is stored with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have saved values of `Date` as numbers. Please check your code once how you are saving and please let us know.

Considering that please try below by passing long values as

```
try {
  Long startDate = 20171114L;
  Long endDate = 20171116L;
  BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
  data.put("Date", new BasicDBObject( new BasicDBObject( "$gte", startDate).append("$lte", endDate)));
} catch(ParseException e){
  e.printStackTrace
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and just did Integer `beginDate = Integer.valueOf(begin)` and `endDate = Integer.valueOf(end)` and it is returning the correct data. However how would I handle if a user enters the end of a month to the start of a next since it would be like 20171031 to 20171101

Comment: If my work helps you then you can up vote that inspires me.

Coming to your doubt,  Your code have to handle start and end date. If we see the calendar 20171031 must be start date and 20171101 must be end date.

Comment: I just tested it and you'd be correct! Love it when the solution is to not have to change anything!